# Get all parents for given element and their siblings

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

I got some table with hierarchy:

```
create table t_hier (id number primary key, parent number);
insert into t_hier (id, parent) values(0, null);
insert into t_hier (id, parent) values(1, 0);
insert into t_hier (id, parent) values(2, 0);
insert into t_hier (id, parent) values(3, 1);
insert into t_hier (id, parent) values(4, 1);
insert into t_hier (id, parent) values(5, 2);
insert into t_hier (id, parent) values(6, 2);
insert into t_hier (id, parent) values(7, 5);
insert into t_hier (id, parent) values(8, 5);

select rpad('* ', 2*level, '* ')||id id, parent
from t_hier
connect by prior id = parent
start with parent is null;

ID                   PARENT
____________________ ______
* 0 
* * 1                0
* * * 3              1
* * * 4              1
* * 2                0
* * * 5              2
* * * * 7            5
* * * * 8            5
* * * 6              2
```

Given some ID I need to get all its parents, grandparents etc and also every sibling of returned elements (by siblings I mean only elements with the same parent, not the entire level), and also given element itself.
So if I have element with id 5, I need to return 0, 1, 2, 5 and 6.
For element with id 7 I need to return 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8.
I think it can be done by just one query, it will be great if someone will help me with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with parents as (
  select level lvl, id
  from t_hier
  start with id = 7
  connect by id = prior parent
)
select distinct id from t_hier
where id != 7
start with id in (select id from parents where lvl > 1)
connect by prior id = parent and level <= 2;
```

1. Find all forefathers
2. Go back and for each forefather find his children but only on the second level
3. Exclude the starting id.

Comment: why not just `select id from t_hier where parent in (
    select parent
    from t_hier
    connect by prior parent = id
    start with id = 7
) or parent is null`? It seems to work too

Comment: @SpongeBobFan Yes, I agree, because you need only one level. Your variant is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

This may help :

```
with cte_getHierarchy (id,parent)
as 
(
  select t_hier.id,t_hier.parent from t_hier where id = 7
  union all
  select t_hier.id,t_hier.parent from t_hier join cte_getHierarchy on t_hier.id = cte_getHierarchy.parent
),
cte_getsibling (id,parent) 
as 
(
  select cte_getHierarchy.id,cte_getHierarchy.parent from cte_getHierarchy 
  union
  select t_hier.id,t_hier.parent from t_hier join cte_getHierarchy on  t_hier.parent = cte_getHierarchy.parent

)
select id from cte_getsibling where id <> 7;
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c5a8c/29)

Answer (score 0):

Should be this one:

```
select rpad('* ', 2*level, '* ')||id id, parent
from t_hier
connect by id = prior parent
start with id = 3
union 
select rpad('* ', 2*level, '* ')||id id, parent
from t_hier
connect by prior id = parent and level = 1
start with parent = (select parent from t_hier where id = 3);
```

Why should id 7 return 0, 1(???), 2, 5, 6, 8.
1 is neither ancestor of 7 nor a sibling.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I need to return siblings for every element in result set, that's why query for id=7 should return element with id=1